# postfix smtp_generic_maps with regular expression

Tags: postfix, regular-expressions, rewritemap

I just started playing around with sender address rewriting with postfix.
I run a server with `debian-7.11` and `postfix-2.9.6`.

Content of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
[...]
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
[...]
```

Content of `/etc/postfix/generic`:

```
santiago@uranus.caoba.fr        santiago.uranus.caoba.fr@caoba-mail.fr
auguste@uranus.caoba.fr         auguste.uranus.caoba.fr@caoba-mail.fr
```

And so far it works. When user `santiago` sends an email, it is sent as `santiago.uranus.caoba.fr@caoba-mail.fr` which is what I want.

My problem is that I want this rewrite to be performed with any user without having to add more lines to `/etc/postfix/generic`. So I was wondering if it could be done via some kind of regular expression like:

```
(.*)@$hostname  $1.$hostname@caoba-mail.fr
```

Is it at all possible?

Thanks for your help

Santiago

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The postfix manual explicitly notes when interpolation in `regexp` or `pcre` tables is forbidden (mostly due to the authors belief that its use is insecure in that context). If the relevant mapping does not say that it is not, interpolation is available by default.

You can do more complex mappings with the SQL lookups, but as long as your host names are fixed and only subdomains of domains you own, regex will entirely suffice.

Install a suitable regexp module for postfix

```
apt install postfix-pcre
```

Add the new `/etc/postfix/generic.pcre` table:

```
/([a-z]+)@([^.]+)\.caoba\.fr/  $1.$2.caoba.fr@caoba-mail.fr
```

Change the table type (*that is replacing your existing `hash`-type mapping!*):

```
postconf -e smtp_generic_maps=pcre:/etc/postfix/generic.pcre
```

You probably still want to check if you have `append_dot_mydomain` enabled (afaik that used to be enabled by default). Debian installs all the relevant manuals, so `man 5 generic` will bring up the explanation.